# Unable to bind a POST request from a form containing a dropdownlist

Tags: razor, servicestack

I am getting a **RequestBindingException** when I POST a form that contains a dropdownlist. Additionally, the server returns a HTTP 400 Bad Request with following POST data:

```
Address1:address1
Address2:address2
City:city
County:County
Countries:GB
PostalCode:test123
```

I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong. Could it be to do with trying to assign the Countries / SelectedCountry properties in the ViewModel's constructor? If so, how should I be assigning initial / default values to these properties?

Or is it a bad idea to use my ViewModel as the endpoint parameter (should it be a separate dto?)

My ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class AddressDetailsViewModel
{
    public AddressDetailsViewModel()
    {
        Countries = new List<SelectListItem>
                        {
                            new SelectListItem
                                {
                                    Selected = true,
                                    Text = "United Kingdom",
                                    Value = "GB"
                                }
                        };

        SelectedCountry = new List<SelectListItem>
                        {
                            new SelectListItem
                                {
                                    Selected = true,
                                    Text = "United Kingdom",
                                    Value = "GB"
                                }
                        };
    }
    ...
}
```

And I'm using the Html Helper to create the dropdown list:

```
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Countries)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Countries, Model.SelectedCountry)
        </li>
```

My Service endpoint (won't get hit) looks like:

```
public object Post(AddressDetailsViewModel data)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is to recommend not using your ViewModel as an endpoint parameter, and instead to design a separate DTO to represent the [message](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Advantages-of-message-based-web-services) that you want to send to the server. If you create a clean message DTO that represents the exact fields you want in your request, with simple get/set properties for each field in the request, then it should be easier to wire this up and get the routing to work in ServiceStack.

There are a few pitfalls to reusing your view model as a request message:

- An MVC style ViewModel is great for describing what to display on your web page, but it's not necessarily a good representation of what the server actually cares about
- The view model is meant to be single purpose, a simple representation of what a specific type of view wants to display
- A DTO representing a request message, on the other hand, can and usually should be more abstract, representing an operation you want to perform on the server (or the identity and state of a resource if you want to be RESTful)
- Your service can and maybe should be able to accept a given type of message from a variety of different clients. What if in the future you want do this sort of action on the server using an Ajax request instead of a form post? Or if you want a mobile app or third party client to integrate with the service? A separate message DTO class that describes the intent of the action on the server rather than reflecting the state of the UI will help here

More specifically, the actual reason you're getting a `RequestBindingException` could be due to a couple of factors, like how your `Countries` property/field is declared in the `AddressDetailsViewModel` class, how the routing is defined for this request compared to how the HTML form is declared, etc. Initializing data in the constructor of your view model shouldn't be relevant to the 400 error you are seeing; I've found that that's a good way to initialize default values for DTOs. Hard to tell without seeing more code.

I'd recommend designing a simpler DTO class for your POST request that only has the properties necessary for the data the server really needs. And to use simpler datatypes - strings and ints instead of SelectListItems or lists of SelectListItems. That will only complicate the request and possibly is involved in the 400 error you are seeing.

Comment: This is also the conclusion I eventually came to, and ended up going down this route. Your points are well explained and helped me understand why this is a better approach.

Comment: Good to hear. Whenever I run into design complications while working on my ServiceStack REST API project, the solution is very often "simplify your DTOs, honor the message-based design". It's like a mantra.